# How to retrieve information from the database without createCommand?

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my controller:

```
$listproduct=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('product')
    ->from('product_form')
    ->where('product_name=:product_name and type=:type', array(':product_name'=>'HP', ':type'=>$gettype ))
    ->queryRow();
```

`$gettype` is responsible for retrieving types of the product. (e.g if the name of the product is HP and `type($gettype)` is PC, it will display the HP product where type is PC). I could not realize this function without `createCommand`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CActiveRecord features

assuming you have a CActiveRecode model class named

```
class ProductForm extends CActiveRecord
{
   /**
   * @return string the associated database table name
   */
   public function tableName()
   {
   .......
```

you could use

For obtain  all the models you can use findAllByAttributes()

```
  $listProduct= ProductForm::model()->
      findAllByAttributes(array('product_name'=>'HP', 'type' =>$gettype ));
```

for obtain a single model you can use findByAttributes()

you can take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar